# Topology: Homeomorphisms

Tags: general-topology

How can I show that the spaces $([0,1), U_{[0,1)})$ and $((-2,0], U_{(-2,0]})$ are homeomorphic (the $U$ in the spaces represents the usual topology)? I have the function $f:([0,1), U_{[0,1)}) \to ((-2,0], U_{(-2,0]})$ defined as $f(x) = -2x$. I have shown it's 1-1, but I'm having trouble with showing onto, continuous, and open. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're probably thinking too hard. Draw a picture!

Comment: i need a formal proof....it's for homework

Comment: Some hints: Onto just means that every point of $(-2,0]$ is in the image of $f$.  Given $x \in (-2,0]$, what point in $[0,1)$ hits it?  For continuous and open, recall that the preimages/images of elements of some basis are open.  Do you know bases for the two topologies you're looking at?  (You can also look at subbases, if you're familiar with them.)  I second Neal's idea to draw a picture.  Even if it's not part of the formal proof, it can help you come up with it.

Comment: no we haven't covered subbases. sorry. would part of the proof be showing that f has an inverse (call it g) and that f and g are inverses of each other?

Answer (score 3):

To get this off the Unanswered list:

You have $f:[0,1)\to(-2,0]:x\mapsto -2x$, and you still need to show that $f$ is surjective (onto), continuous, and open.

- $f$ is surjective (onto): Suppose that $y\in (-2,0]$; is there necessarily an $x\in[0,1)$ such that $f(x)=y$? Clearly $f\left(-\frac{y}2\right)=y$, so you need only check that $-\frac{y}2\in[0,1)$, which is straightforward manipulation of inequalities.
- $f$ is continuous: If you don’t see any nicer way, you can always fall back on a calculus-style $\epsilon$-$\delta$ argument; taking $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}2$ will work.
- $f$ is open: Since $f$ is a bijection, this is precisely the same as proving that $f^{-1}$ is continuous. In this case it’s easy to work out explicitly what the function $f^{-1}$ is: I essentially did it in the first bullet point. And the previous comment applies equally well to $f^{-1}$, except that you’ll have to change the relationship between $\epsilon$ and $\delta$.